# enter tomorrows date in the text field

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to enter tomorrow's date in the date text field, but my script below enters today's date. Can you please look at the code and let me know what I am missing. Thanks!

My Script:

```
public void setThePuaseRemoveTheStartDate() {
Date dt = new Date();

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(dt);
calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
dt = calendar.getTime();


String todaysDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(new Date());
todaysDate.equals(dt);

//enter tomorrow's date in the Pause field
WebElement tomDate = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='in']"));
tomDate.sendKeys(todaysDate);

}
```

Comment: Pass dt instead of todaysDate to tomDate.sendKeys()

Comment: you're setting `tomDate` with `todaysDate` I think you might have to pass `dt` into `String todaysDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(dt);` instead of `new Date()` and I'd rename `todaysDate` to be `tomorrowsDate` or something

Comment: @SuckerForMayhem ----- this fixed it..      String todaysDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(dt);

Comment: does it work? I'm not a usual Java guy, so not exactly sure on your use of `Calendar` and `getTime()` maybe should be `getDate()` or `getDateTime()` would make more sense?

Comment: Yes Sir, it did!.... it enters 01/29/2015 now. You Rock!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a mistake here : `String todaysDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(new Date());`, shouldn't be `String todaysDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(dt);` instead ?